# ng-repeat isn't loading my array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that returns several jsons via rest requests, and the data of these jsons are stored in a array.

Then this array put in $scope and use it in a ng-repeat, but isn't working.

//JS

```
async function exec_q(access_token, start_date,end_date,programa_gql){
   var people = [];
...requests and filling the array...
   people.push({
      "atrib1": res.1 === null ? '' : res.1,
      "atrib2": res.2 === null ? '' : res.2
   }
   return people
}

people = await exec_q(access_token, start_date,end_date,programa_gql)
$scope.people = people
```

//HTML

```
<tbody id="table_apd_body">
   <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
      <th>{{{$index + 1}}</th>
      <th>{{p.atrib1}}</th>
      <th>{{p.atrib2}}</th>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Obs:. the function that call the code above is async as well to make the await works.

Comment: you're missing closing parenthesis after push function.

Comment: angularjs doesn't work with async/await

Answer (score 3):

The ES6 promises used by `async`/`await` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

```
people = await exec_q(access_token, start_date,end_date,programa_gql)
$scope.people = people

$scope.$apply();
```

Use `$apply` to integrate `$scope` changes.

Answer (score 0):

//Remove extra { in {{$index + 1}}

```
<tbody id="table_apd_body">
   <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
      <th>{{$index + 1}}</th>
      <th>{{p.atrib1}}</th>
      <th>{{p.atrib2}}</th>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```